# jQuery - calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, call

```
function initiate()
{

    $("p").text("Hi", Hello());
}

function Hello()
{
    alert("Hello, you have called another function");
}
```

HTML:

```
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<button onclick="initiate()">Click me</button>
```

Right now the script calls the function initiate() upon the button click, and then the other function, Hello() is called, while changing all paragraphs in the html to "Hi".

What I would like is that the function Initiate() will call the function Hello() using jQuery, and do nothing else.

(In other words, how do I simply call a function using jQuery?)

Comment: Well, how do you call a function in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you don't really need jquery for this, but if you are dead set on using it, you should re-evaluate your logic here.
Give your button an id first, you don't need it, but it's good to do it anyway:

```
<button id="btnClickMe">Click Me<button>
```

then, use that to trigger a jquery event on, thus calling your function:

```
$('#btnClickMe').click(function() { //You can either link directly to a func here
alert('Whatever'); //Or you can write the code for your func directly into the handler here
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could not pass callback function to [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Call the `hello` method after changing the text.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hNqYB/)**

Change

```
$("p").text("Hi", Hello());
```

To

```
$("p").text("Hi");
Hello();
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me, it doesn't call the function Hello() - what I would like is to call the function without having to change the <p> elements.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to call Hello() from Initiate(), you simply call it as follows:

```
function initiate()
{

    Hello();
}
```

Comment: He doesn't just want to call `Hello`, he wants to set the text on a paragraph to `Hi` as well.

Comment: This is what I'd like to do, just with jQuery. is that possible?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to set the text on the paragraph? If so, what was wrong with the initial code?

Otherwise, jQuery is in javascript, so you can use normal javascript syntax within jQuery.

Comment: +1. Exactly what OP wants: "the function Initiate() will call the function Hello() using jQuery, and do nothing else."

Answer (score 0):

> What I would like is that the function Initiate() will call the
>   function Hello() using jQuery, and do nothing else.

You don't need to call the function using jQuery, you can just call it.

```
function initiate()
{

    $("p").text("Hi");
    Hello();
}
```

The function argument taken by `.text` is not the second argument and neither is it  for calling that function like you are trying to do. It is for setting the text of each paragraph individually by returning a value from the passed function. Since you want the text "Hi" in each paragraph, you can just use `$("p").text("Hi")`.

Answer (score 0):

This will attach an event handler that is fired when the button is clicked.  You will not need the `initialize` function anymore nor will you need to set the text on the `p`.  I'm having trouble discerning what you would like, however I think you may just want to call the function on a simple click of the button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     Hello();
  });
});
```